# Efeito desenho a lapis com opencv e python

Tags: python, opencv, processamento-de-imagens

Quero obter o resultado da imagem mais a direita, no entando só consigo chegar ao da imagem do meio, usando filtro de canny e um filtro gaussiano. Alguém sabe como posso obter esse resultado?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread("foto.jpg", 0 )
cany = cv2.Canny(img,100,200)
cany = 255 - cany
cany = cv2.GaussianBlur(cany, (5,5),0)
cv2.imshow('resultado', cany)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import cv2

# abrindo a imagem em escala de cinza
img_gray = cv2.imread('wonder-woman.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# calculando o inverso, 255 é branco 0 é preto e aplicando o blur
img_gray_inv = 255 - img_gray
img_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img_gray_inv, (21,21), 0, 0)

# fazemos o blend com o cv2.divide
img_blend = cv2.divide(img_gray, 255 - img_blur, scale = 256)

#salvamos
cv2.imwrite('wonder-woman-v1.png',img_blend)
```

1. Converta a imagem colorida em tons de cinza.
2. Inverta a imagem em tons de cinza para obter um negativo.
3. Aplique um Blur Guassiano ao negativo da etapa 2.
4. Combine a imagem em tons de cinza da etapa 1 com o negativo desfocado da etapa 3 usando um Color Dodge.

[image: Entrada]

[image: Saída]

Fonte para a resolução você encontra neste livro [aqui](https://www.amazon.com.br/OpenCV-Blueprints-English-Michael-Beyeler-ebook/dp/B014T58O1I/ref=sr_1_1?__mk_pt_BR=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&crid=1R33CZRX55P23&dchild=1&keywords=opencv+python+blueprints&qid=1611604947&sprefix=opencv+%2Caps%2C283&sr=8-1).

Comment: 